# How to perform a MySQL insert via jQuery/Ajax within the Zend Framework

Tags: mysql, ajax, zend-framework

**A quick brief background:**

I am in the process of creating a drawing program that uses the HTML 5 canvas element.  I would like to have the user to be able to save the contents of their drawing at any given time.  So far, I am able to create an array that holds the contents of the drawing via javascript.

**What I would like to do:**

What I am trying to do now is create a 'Save' Button that upon being pressed, the array is inserted into a MySQL Table.  I am currently trying to teach myself how to do this via jQuery/Ajax within the Zend Framework.  The only thing that I'm not sure about is how do I get the Zend Controller to receive the data from the Ajax request.

This is what I have so far:

Code snippet from **index.phtml:**

```
<button type="submit" id="saveButton" name="saveButton">Save</button>
<script type"text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {           
        $("#saveButton").click(function()
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "/CableDesign/public/create-drawing/save",
                data: drawingArray,
                type: "POST",
                success: function(response){ alert('Success!'); }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Code snippet from my controller: **CreateDrawingController.php**

```
  public function indexAction()
{
        if($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        // This is where I would retrieve my array from the Ajax request and insert its contents into my database table.
        $drawingArray = $this->getParam('drawingContents');
        $drawingModel = new Application_Model_DbTable_DrawingModel();
        $boolInsert = $drawingModel->insertContents($drawingArray);

        if ($boolInsert)
            $this->view->message = "Successful save!";
        else
            $this->view->message = "Fail to save your drawing.";
    }
    }
```

From the above-mentioned code, I know that I am going about this all wrong and I was wondering if anyone out there can help me through this process.  Thank you so much in advance.

**Edit:**

I made the changes that sudol suggested, here is the final copy of the code that I got to work:

My updated Controller **CreateDrawingController.php**:

```
    class CreateDrawingController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {

    }

    public function indexAction()
    {

    }

    public function saveAction()
    {
        if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest())
        {
            //$drawingArray = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            $drawingArray = $this->getRequest()->getParam('drawingArray');
            $drawingModel = new Application_Model_DbTable_DrawingModel;
            $boolInsert = $drawingModel->insertContents($drawingArray);

            if ($boolInsert)
                $this->view->message = "Successful save!";
            else
                $this->view->message = "Fail to save your drawing.";
        }
    }

    private function printArray($array)
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($array);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

The updated code snippet in my **index.phtml**

```
<script type"text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {           
        $("#saveButton").click(function()
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "/CableDesign/public/create-drawing/save",
                data: { drawingArray : drawingArray },
                type: "POST",
                success: function(response){ alert('Success!'); }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The Internal Server 500 Errors were being caused by two things:

1. I had left out the parentheses in the getRequest portion of the following if statement:

   `if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest())`
2. I had forgotten to enable layouts and I enabled them via Zend's CLI Tools for Windows using the following command:

   `zf enable layout`

Thanks for all the help sudol! Hope this helps anyone else out there. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close,

using your ajax call:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: "/public/create-drawing/save",
        data: drawingContents,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(response){
        alert('Success!');
    }
});
```

You will want a new Action in your `CreateDrawingController` called `saveAction` instead of the `indexAction`. You can retrieve the data by doing `$this->getRequest()->getParams()`, then save it as you are doing. Something like:

```
public function saveAction()
{
    if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        $drawingArray = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $drawingModel = new Application_Model_DbTable_DrawingModel();
        $boolInsert = $drawingModel->insertContents($drawingArray);

        if ($boolInsert)
            $this->view->message = "Successful save!";
        else
            $this->view->message = "Fail to save your drawing.";
    }
}
```

**Note:** I did not test this code! But I think it's correct. You are very close in the first place.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hey sudol, thanks so much for replying! I am starting to get 500 Internal Server Errors, see my edit up above.

Comment: Hmmmm... you should also have a save.phtml in your views/scripts folder, it can be blank. Is that in there?

Comment: Thanks again sudol.  The 500 Internal Server Error was due to the missing () around getRequest in the if statement which was changed to `code`if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()).  Firebug is now showing that it's receiving the array.  However, I get another Internal Server Error whenever I declare my database object:  $drawingModel = new Application_Model_DbTable_DrawingModel(). <br /> I'm not sure why it would bug out when I am calling for a new object.  Anything that you can think of? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Update:  I finally got it to insert into the MySQL table.  The Internal Server Errors were due to the fact that I didn't have layouts enabled.  I am using the CLI Tool for Windows and I resolved this by typing in the following:  zf enable layout.  I'm going to update my code once more to show the working solution.  Thanks so much for helping me out sudol. :)